# How to use commands to give a shield in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

In later Minecraft versions I can not find the shield in the items list for commands I want to give it to players like swords and crossbows but it just isn't there? 1.18.1

Comment: Which *precise* version of Minecraft, and what kind of list are you looking at? Because I can certainly see the ID at [fandom](https://minecraft.fandom.com/wiki/Shield).

Comment: When you are doing /give and press tab you can see all the items

Answer (score 0):

You need to put "minecraft:" before the item you want to get/give. Examples:

For a shield

```
/give @p minecraft:shield
```

For swords:

```
/give @p minecraft:diamond_sword
```

Change "diamond" to any material that you can use to make swords (**NOT** including sticks)

You can also add "[distance=..3]" right after @p to tell the command block to give  to the closes player that is within 3 blocks of distance. you can also change @p to @a to say all players within 3 blocks
Examples:

```
/give @p[distance=..3] minecraft:diamond_sword
/give @a[distance=..3] minecraft:diamond_sword
```

Comment: That doesn't work for me I have been putting Minecraft:sheild

Comment: for one, you do not need to explicitly add `minecraft:` as the game will attempt to use that namespace ID anyway. however, @CiurkitboyN, if you *are* trying to add it, it *must* be lower case.